# javascript foreach increase number

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var dd = Math.floor(Math.random()*99);    
$('#a'+ dd + 'b'+ dd + 'c'+ d ).css({...});



for (var i=1; i<100; i++) {
 for (var ii=1; ii<100; ii++) {
  for (var iii=1; iii<100; iii++) {
   $('#a'+ i + 'b' + ii + 'c' + iii).css({...});
  }
 }
}
```

I need help changing the div css which id number like `div#a` + num + `b` + num + `c` + num, (num range from 1-99 so that like `div#a11b35c9`, `div#a98b23c17` ...)

Random cannot delimit all the number range from (1-99) foreach make judge slowly. How do I make it more efficient? (It is also hard to add a class for each div) Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the three `for` loops are doing what you want. What is the problem with that approach? Please explain more.

Comment: @Jonathan M, yes, it is a tree for loops. not all the div from a1b1c1 to a99b99c99, but if they are have, how to call all the div `div#a + num + b + num + c + num, (num range from 1-99)`? in my foreach loop, it will dead, so do u have good idea?

Comment: You want the number to be the same after a, b and c? div#a3b3c3 and div#a52b52c52 are good, but div#a4b72c23 is not?

Comment: Oh, you're wanting to loop through all divs that match /^a\d{1,2}b\d{1,2}c\d{1,2}$/ Right?

Comment: @Jonathan M, `div#a4b72c23` still in the range, `a b c` are not equal. there are two answers work for me, but do u have good idea for a foreach or function way to call 1-99 for a,b,c? Thanks for teach.

Comment: @Jonathan M, yes, as your regular expression.

Comment: See if my answer is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
divArray=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (mydiv in divArray) {
    if (mydiv.id.match(/^a\d{1,2}b\d{1,2}c\d{1,2}$/)) {
        // make your change here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not add a class to all of those `<div>` tags and do this:

```
$('.myDivs').css({ ... });
```

You might be able to get away with something like this, if adding a class isn't feasible:

```
$('div[id^=a][id*=b][id*=c]').css({ ... });
```

Comment: This will also get `<div id="abracadabra">`, which shouldn't be included.

Comment: @Jonathan M: That's why I said "might be able to get away with something like this". If the divs in question are the only ones on the page, then the second suggestion will work. Otherwise, I would recommend my first suggestion.

Comment: @Gordo: see my response to your comment under ain's answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('div[id^="a"]')
```

this would give you all divs which have `id` starting with "a", but this resultset needs furhter filtering if you do use "regular" ids which also start with "a".

Comment: This will also get a `<div id="apple">`, which should not be included per the OP.

Comment: Yes, the "resultset" would need further filtering, perhaps using regexp like in your solution. Benefit of this solution is that the initial resultset to work with would be smaller.

Comment: @Jonathan M: That fact only matters if the OP has a div with id "apple". The solution doesn't have to be perfect for every possible instance, just this one.

Comment: @Gordo: Yeah, I understand that. But the problem lies in that the next schmuck who's asked to make a change to the page may not know this bit of tribal knowledge, and so he may actually add a div that gets caught by this inexact filter.

Comment: You're point is valid. Still, I don't think this answer and mine are "wrong" enough to be down-voted (if that was indeed you).